# Resetting MacOS Window Backing Store

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

I'm building a macOS app that has a custom window (inheriting from NSWindow), with, among other things, a custom way of resizing it.

In the process of writing and debugging the resize code, I accidentally resized the window to an arbitrarily large value.  No problem, I'm thinking.  I just reverted the code to what had been working.

But now I'm getting this error before the window can even load:

```
2020-08-08 08:22:22.777588-0700 MyApp[1679:21967] -[<_NSViewBackingLayer: 0x600000c86220> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (57500.000000, 57500.000000), contentsScale 2.000000, backing store size (115000.000000, 115000.000000)
```

My window is 300x300 pixels.  Somehow macOS decided to make a backing store for me that is 115000x115000.  This state survives a reboot.  Ugh.

I have a workaround, which is to specifically set a new identifier in the .xib.  So it looks to me like the system is committed to maintaining state for my window based on the id.

Instead of accumulating a bunch of state whenever I have a bug in my code, I'd much rather fix the root cause.

Where is this state being held?  Is there any way to reset it?

Comment: An NSWindow has a backing store type. What's yours?

Comment: It's the default, 'buffered'.  Other types appear to be deprecated:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/backingstoretype

Comment: Indeed, but I wonder whether setting it to another value, like nonretained, would be another way out of this. — Another possibility, of course, would be to throw out the cache that's being stored for you maintaining the app state. You know where that is, right?

Comment: Er, no, I don't know where that is, which is what my core question is.  Ideally, I'd like my app to be able to force it to be cleared out.

Comment: Well, I don't know about your app, but _you_ can probably clear it out. Delete Xcode's derived data folder and also delete the app's saved application state folder. Do a search on your app's bundle id as a file/folder name if you don't know where those are.

Comment: Try starting the app holding the Shift key. Xcode has a "Launch application without state restoration" debug setting (Edit Scheme).

Answer (score 1):

The "backing store" is a red herring. The issue is simply the saved size of the window.

You can maybe fix this by doing:

```
defaults delete <your app's bundle ID> "NSWindow Frame <you window's autosave name>"
```

If you don't mind nuking all of your app's preferences, you can just do:

```
defaults delete <your app's bundle ID>
```

Alternatively, you may need to delete your app's window restoration saved state. For a non-sandboxed app, that would be in ~/Library/SavedApplicationState/<your app's bundle ID>.savedState. For a sandboxed app, it's in the app's container at ~/Library/Containers/<your app's bundle ID>/Data/Library/SavedApplicationState/<your app's bundle ID>.savedState.

Comment: defaults read <app bundle id> comes up empty.  Maybe because it's not really installed?

Comment: No such thing as "really installed" or not. What about the restoration saved state (last paragraph)?

Comment: I do see my bundle ides in ~/Library/Containers, but not in ~/Libary/SavedApplicationState.  I need to do some work to repro this, but I want to leave the question open for a bit in case someone knows how to clean this up programmatically.